# How do I pass objects from Javascript to C++ using Emscripten

Tags: javascript, c++, llvm-clang, emscripten

I want to pass back a Javascript object from JS to C++ class/method.
I have the following simple code snippet which is not working:

```
// Access JS objects in C++ like C++ objects

#include "emscripten/val.h"   //Causing errors !

using namespace emscripten;
int main() {
    val Math = val::global("Math");
    return Math.call("abs", -10); // returns 10
}
```

I use the following to compile using emscripten on windows :

> cmd> emcc Access_Objects.cpp

I get huge log of errors :

```
In file included from Access_Objects.cpp:2:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\inclu
de\emscripten/val.h:4:
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:2
4:5: error:
      unknown type name 'constexpr'
    constexpr bool has_unbound_type_names = true;
    ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:2
4:15: error:
      expected unqualified-id
    constexpr bool has_unbound_type_names = true;
              ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:5
6:21: error:
      use of undeclared identifier 'has_unbound_type_names'
                if (has_unbound_type_names || std::is_polymorphic<C>::value) {
                    ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:6
7:17: error:
      use of undeclared identifier 'has_unbound_type_names'
            if (has_unbound_type_names || std::is_polymorphic<C>::value) {
                ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:8
2:40: error:
      a space is required between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >')
        struct TypeID<std::unique_ptr<T>> {
                                       ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:9
8:42: error:
      a space is required between consecutive right angle brackets (use '> >')
        struct TypeID<AllowedRawPointer<T>> {
                                         ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
82:9: error:
      unknown type name 'constexpr'
        EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE(char);
        ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
74:13: note:
      expanded from macro 'EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE'
            constexpr static WireType toWireType(const type& v) {   \
            ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
82:9: error:
      expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
        EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE(char);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
74:23: note:
      expanded from macro 'EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE'
            constexpr static WireType toWireType(const type& v) {   \
            ~~~~~~~~~ ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
83:9: error:
      unknown type name 'constexpr'
        EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE(signed char);
        ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
74:13: note:
      expanded from macro 'EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE'
            constexpr static WireType toWireType(const type& v) {   \
            ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
83:9: error:
      expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
        EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE(signed char);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
74:23: note:
      expanded from macro 'EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE'
            constexpr static WireType toWireType(const type& v) {   \
            ~~~~~~~~~ ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
84:9: error:
      unknown type name 'constexpr'
        EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE(unsigned char);
        ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
74:13: note:
      expanded from macro 'EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE'
            constexpr static WireType toWireType(const type& v) {   \
            ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
84:9: error:
      expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
        EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE(unsigned char);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
74:23: note:
      expanded from macro 'EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE'
            constexpr static WireType toWireType(const type& v) {   \
            ~~~~~~~~~ ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
85:9: error:
      unknown type name 'constexpr'
        EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE(signed short);
        ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
74:13: note:
      expanded from macro 'EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE'
            constexpr static WireType toWireType(const type& v) {   \
            ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
85:9: error:
      expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
        EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE(signed short);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
74:23: note:
      expanded from macro 'EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE'
            constexpr static WireType toWireType(const type& v) {   \
            ~~~~~~~~~ ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
86:9: error:
      unknown type name 'constexpr'
        EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE(unsigned short);
        ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
74:13: note:
      expanded from macro 'EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE'
            constexpr static WireType toWireType(const type& v) {   \
            ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
86:9: error:
      expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
        EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE(unsigned short);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
74:23: note:
      expanded from macro 'EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE'
            constexpr static WireType toWireType(const type& v) {   \
            ~~~~~~~~~ ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
87:9: error:
      unknown type name 'constexpr'
        EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE(signed int);
        ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
74:13: note:
      expanded from macro 'EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE'
            constexpr static WireType toWireType(const type& v) {   \
            ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
87:9: error:
      expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
        EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE(signed int);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
74:23: note:
      expanded from macro 'EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE'
            constexpr static WireType toWireType(const type& v) {   \
            ~~~~~~~~~ ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
88:9: error:
      unknown type name 'constexpr'
        EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE(unsigned int);
        ^
C:\Program Files\Emscripten\emscripten\1.16.0\system\include\emscripten/wire.h:1
74:13: note:
      expanded from macro 'EMSCRIPTEN_DEFINE_NATIVE_BINDING_TYPE'
            constexpr static WireType toWireType(const type& v) {   \
            ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
ERROR    root: compiler frontend failed to generate LLVM bitcode, halting
```

The error is being caused in 'wire.h' which is included in 'emscripten/val.h'.

How do I resolve these errors? Or
Is there any other way to pass objects from JS to C++ ?

Comment: Another way to pass objects: http://leaningtech.com/cheerp/

Comment: It's using C++11 features, so the correct command would be `em++ -std=c++11 Access_Objects.cpp`

Answer (score 6):

There are other ways to interact between JS and C++.  The most stable way that I've found is to build your own library by wrapping JS functions so that you can call them from C++.

If you want to call Javascript's Math.abs() from C++, you can edit "src/library.JS".  In there you'll find a giant map of function names that are available in C++.  If you wanted to call your new function "JS_Math_abs", you would add:

```
JS_Math_abs: function(value) {
  return Math.abs(value);
},
```

Then you would modify your C++ code to specify input and output types.  Add:

```
extern "C" {
  extern int JS_Math_abs(int);
}
```

Don't get me wrong, this method is more annoying than val should be (were it working properly), but it should also be more efficient in the end.  Once you have the main libraries you need wrapped, you'll find it's very stable.  For the most part, however, it's easy to use the C++ versions of functions like abs().

You can find out more about creating your own libraries here: http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-call-javascript-from-native

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you need to pass -std=c++11 to the compiler as its using c++11